# I want to find the average frequency of going out of a particular age group in a month

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis

I've a data of particular age group and their frequency of going out that is how many times they go out.

[image]

As you can see I've the data how many people go out once a month, once a week and so on. But I want to find out the weighted average of people going out in a month for a particular age group.

[image]

Expecting output something like this!!

Comment: What error did you get with your code? Or what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I'm not able to think about the scale how to convert all this into a particular scale i.e. on monthly basis. Right now we are having twice a week, quarterly basis